# Get first result of suggested results with Wikipedia's API

Tags: json, request, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to use Wikipedia's API, but I can't find a way to get the first result when there are multiple possible ones.

For example if I use [this request](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts%7Cimages&titles=test&redirects=1&explaintext=1&imlimit=20) `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts%7Cimages&titles=test&redirects=1&explaintext=1&imlimit=20` it will return an article that says

> Test may refer to: ...

What I want is for it to skip this part and give me directly the results of the first result that *"Test may refer to"*.

Do you know if this is possible or not ?

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: When you receive the results of the query how do you process them? I mean, what language or system do you use?

Comment: Javascript. I'm building a nodejs app

Comment: It's not possible, the extract always starts at the beginning of the article. You can use `exlimit` to make the snippet longer, and then manually cut out the "refer to" part somehow.